# using nl2br to insert a line break only once rather than before each new line

Tags: php, nl2br

I have a string and i am using `nl2br` to insert line breaks.

how can i make it only insert one new line break before all newlines rather than a line break before all new lines

Comment: Can't understand what you do need. Can you post an example?

Comment: You could try to first replace all occurrences of more than one new line with one new line then run it through `nl2br`

Answer (score 0):

You could use preg_replace() afterwards to match all repeating BR's and replace with a single one

```
$pattern = "/(\<br\/\>)+/i";
$replacement = "<br/>";
$subject = "hi<br/><br/><br/>how are<br/>you";
$limit = -1;
$count = 0;
$result = preg_replace ($pattern, $replacement, $subject, $limit, $count);
```